# Sealing wet wood?

Tags: finishing, wood

I recently purchased a slab of black walnut and am needing to make a desk out of it sooner rather than later. Am I able to just finish the top side of the table and leave the bottom of it unsealed so it can dry while I use it or is this risking ruining the piece of wood all together?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. I was just writing an Answer and realised it's not clear if the slab was green or partially green..... this does appear to be implied by the Q but I didn't want to assume. Can you clarify please? If you don't know the current dried status it would be important to get some info from the seller on when the slab was cut and how it's been stored since.

Comment: In addition to the questions above, how is this going to be built into a desk? Is it just the slab placed on a structure, or will it be more intricately joined? How wide is it (perpendicular to the grain)? Would you be willing to temporarily place thin plexiglass on top instead of a finish?

Comment: Yes, you are 100% able to finish just the top side and leave the bottom unsealed. Most furniture through the ages has been built this way. _However_, depending on the current moisture content, yes you risk ruining the piece. Consider dropping a piece of glass on top as a temporary top surface (supported by several rubber feet to allow air flow underneath) if you _must_ put the wood into service immediately. Then you can disassemble and finish in a year or two when the top has thoroughly dried. (Roughly 1 year per inch of thickness to air dry from green. Less if it's partially dry now.)